# the page from which the user is visiting the current page

Tags: php

I have a web site with several pages. Page1, Page2, .. etc

I don't want the user to visit Page2 posting its URL directly in the browser because Page2 should be visited only from Page1. In PHP, what should I code in Page2 to know that the user was before in Page1 and clicked a link or something that brough him or her to Page2? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [PHP sessions](http://se.php.net/manual/en/book.session.php).

**page1.php**

```
session_start();
$_SESSION['pages_visited'][basename(__FILE__)] = true;
```

**page2.php**

```
session_start();
$_SESSION['pages_visited'][basename(__FILE__)] = true;

if (!isset($_SESSION['pages_visited']['page1.php']) || !$_SESSION['pages_visited']['page1.php']) {
    header('Location: page1.php');
    exit;
}
```

Comment: +1 - `HTTP_REFERER` is supplied by the user and not to be trusted

Answer (score 4):

You could use

```
 $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']
```

though you can't rely on it being set every time.

Answer (score 0):

In order to implement reliable mechanism, you may use sessions mechanism: http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.session.php

In this case information about visited pages can be stored on server side and will be retrieved by session id, which is stored in user's cookies / GET/POST variables